# How to get input value with ajax in a while loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get two input values when a button is clicked. I do not have a form, just two hidden input fields in a while statement. The values change depending on which plan the user chooses. Right now the problem I have I'm unable to get the two values. The rest works. I'm able to trigger the modal.

**index.php**

```
//...queries
while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans)) {;// output data of each row
<input type="hidden" name="planname" class="planname" value="'.$plan['name'].'">
<input type="hidden" name="planlvl" class="planlvl" value="'.$plan['level'].'">
<button type="button" class="viewdetail btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default">VIEW DETAILS</button>
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.viewdetail').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //show modal
             $('#planmodal').modal('show');

            //get variables
            var valuename=$(this).find('.planname').val();
            var valuelevel=$(this).find('.planlvl').val();

            if(valuename!=='' && valuelevel!==''){
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'includes/getplan.php',
                data:"{'planname':'"+valuename+"','planlvl':'"+valuelevel+"'}",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#plandetails").html(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            var error = 'Nothing to show here';
            $("#plandetails").html(error);
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe you're not getting what you expect when using $('this). Looking at your code, that would return whatever was clicked. Try console.logging $(this) to see what the returned DOM object is.

Comment: $('.planname') and $('.planlvl') I think is what you are looking for. As stated in the previous comment, "this" is whatever event jquery is working with. Since viewdetail is a button, it would not have a value.

Comment: @RyanGibbs: Thanks dude. But I got it solved already. See my response below :)

Comment: @SynchroDynamic: It works now. See my response below.

Answer (score 0):

After a few works around, the solution below works for me. I'm posting full code for testing.

**index.php**

```
//...queries
while($plan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultplans)) {;// output data of each row
<button type="button" dataname="'.$plan['name'].'" datalevel="'.$plan['level'].'" class="viewdetail btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default">VIEW DETAILS</button>
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.viewdetail').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //show modal
             $('#planmodal').modal('show');

            //get variables
             var valuename = $(this).attr("dataname");
             var valuelevel = $(this).attr("datalevel");
             var values = 'planname='+ encodeURIComponent(valuename) + '&planlvl='+ encodeURIComponent(valuelevel); // this where i add multiple data using  ' & '

            if(values!==''){
                $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'includes/getplan.php',
                data:values,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#plandetails").html(data);
                }
            });
        }else{
            var error = 'Nothing to show here';
            $("#plandetails").html(error);
        }
        });
    });
```

**getplan.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['planname']) && $_POST['planlvl']){

    $planname = $_POST['planname'];
    $planlvl = $_POST['planlvl'];

    echo 'Post success';// replace this with usual query. This is just for testing.


}else{
    echo 'Post failed';//replace this with custom message.
}
```

**modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="planmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Dynamic Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="plandetails"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**output in the bootstrap modal :**

```
Post success
```

Comment: That's a round about way to do it, but if ot works for you then thats what matters.